# Чи можна вживати вислів "летіти/полетіти в тартарари"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Цікавить чи можна вживати в українській мові вислів "летіти в тартарари".

Почув цю фразу російською "лететь в тартарары" і означає вона "[невідомо куди дітися, зникнути](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=XyLlDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT251&lpg=PT251&dq=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=3VoEvYOyGL&sig=MRho3gLmCXEzlCtUYXyU1nT63ok&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrv_yEuO3fAhWFs4sKHRSLAE04ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B&f=false)". Але як виявилося можна зустріти цей вислів і в українських книжках. Наприклад, переклад книги "[Коли подих стає повітрям](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=wpx7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&lpg=PT61&dq=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=IMeP-CpfiS&sig=Oet3RjVEGh1pKc8Ss30QTIM5QUk&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig14S7t-3fAhUG_SoKHRsIBUQQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%22&f=false)":

> Мій розклад полетів тартарари

Або в книзі української письменниці Раїси Плотникової "[Афганський кут крилатої Серафими](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ZYR0DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT224&lpg=PT224&dq=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=pmXi26vv01&sig=_2wM8-0-3Yag9f9Rge99IKqzY7Y&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig14S7t-3fAhUG_SoKHRsIBUQQ6AEwDXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%22&f=false)":

> ... голова полетіла в тартарари...

Саме слово "тартарари" походить від слова "[Тартар](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B)". Однак, якщо "[Тартар](http://sum.in.ua/s/tartar)" є в СУМі, то слова "тартарари" там немає.

То чи можна вживати цей вислів? Чи краще замінити його?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Вашому запитання є посилання на значення виразу на книгу російською мовою, де вказано:

> так и появилось выражение ["провалится в тартарары"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=XyLlDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT251&lpg=PT251&dq=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=3VoEvYOyGL&sig=MRho3gLmCXEzlCtUYXyU1nT63ok&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrv_yEuO3fAhWFs4sKHRSLAE04ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B&f=false)

*"Провалится в тартарары"* - це фразеологізм російської мови.  Переклад даного виразу знаходимо в [Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)[2](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> • Провалиться в тартарары (разг.) – ***крізь землю провалитися*** (піти); у
> землю увійти; казна-де подітися.

В [Фразеологічному словнику української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53407/360634.html)

> ***як*** (мов, на́че і т. ін.) ***крізь зе́млю провали́вся***. Раптово, безслідно
> і т. ін. зник хтось, зникло що-небудь. І *зник (чоловік) так само
> несподівано, як і появився. Я .. все хотів побачити його знову, щоб
> розпитати добре про тих богатирів, але він як крізь землю провалився*
> (Легенди..);

На мою думку, вираз ***"полетіти/летіти в тартарари"*** просто недолугий переклад з російської, тому краще вживати фразеологізм ***"мов крізь землю провалився"*** для ознаки "зникнути".